# Javascript show element on click

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to do this without Jquery. I want to show a div when clicking a trigger. So far I have this to hide the element.

```
 document.getElementById('element').style.display = 'none';
```

HTML..

```
<div class="element">Ahem, boo!!</div>
<a href="#" id="showDiv">Show</a>
```

How do I create a function to show the div when clicking the link? I would like to avoid using functions like `onclick="showDiv()` in the link itself.

Comment: whydo you want to avoid using the onclick event?  Your only other option is <a href="javascript:showDiv()">, but that's no better...

Comment: If the link is hidden, how can you click on it?

Comment: @idealmachine, sorry I edited the code

Comment: Note that your markup looks strongly like you're abusing HTML anchors for JavaScript hooks, which you should not do. Use a `<button>` and style it to look like a link, if you like, but don't use an HTML anchor.

Comment: @Phrogs, I assumed that it's like jquery. Would you disagree?

Comment: @CyberJunkie I'm not sure what you mean by that question.

Comment: @Cyber Junkie: For the edited code, did you mean `id="element"` or not?

Comment: @MikeRuhlin Your comment is very incorrect. There is absolutely an alternative (more than one, in fact) to mixing your JavaScript in with your HTML markup. You should eschew the `onclick` attribute in HTML, along with all other JavaScript event handlers in your HTML.

Comment: @Phrogz I mean, using HTML anchors like <a> is done a lot in Jquery. Is it not ok with plain js?

Comment: @CyberJunkie If you are programmatically generating the HTML anchors and injecting them into the DOM, it's marginally acceptable. It is not OK if your HTML is sent from the server to the browser with such semantically-incorrect anchors. jQuery, however, is irrelevant here. The fact that plenty of people improperly use jQuery, Prototype, and other JavaScript libraries with their HTML does not make it correct.

Comment: Oooh I see! Using HTML anchors is very efficient tho.. Hopefully js will support this improper coding in the future.

Comment: @phrogz, when I made my comment I was considering setting the onlick attribute via HTML or Javascript to be equivalent to each other.
The fact is, your solution is WORSE than setting it straight on the HTML because it makes it harder to debug.  In one case, I can inspect an element in Firebug and see the onclick event right there.  In the other, I have to search through javascript that might wire it up by ID, class name, or tag name.

Comment: @CyberJunkie It's not syntactically unsupported. JavaScript supports it just fine (just as it does with applying click handlers to other elements as well). It's simply the wrong HTML markup for the task at hand, just as using `blockquote` to visually indent content that is not a quote is incorrect.

Comment: Duplicate of [Show/hide 'div' using JavaScript](/q/21070101/4642212). There are far better answers over there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('showDiv').onclick=function(){
  // Remove any element-specific value, falling back to stylesheets
  document.getElementById('element').style.display='';
};
```

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to attach event handlers completely within JavaScript. Example:

```
document.getElementById('showDiv').onclick = function() {
    // Do whatever now that the user has clicked the link.
};
```

To reverse the effect of the first line of code you posted, you could use:

```
document.getElementById('element').style.display = 'block'; // or
document.getElementById('element').style.display = '';
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this to the script:

```
function myFunction() {

            var btn = document.getElementById("myButton");
            //to make it fancier
            if (btn.value == "Click To Open") {
                btn.value = "Click To Close";
                btn.innerHTML = "Click To Close";
            }
            else {
                btn.value = "Click To Open";
                btn.innerHTML = "Click To Open";
            }
            //this is what you're looking for
            var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
```

and edit the button and div:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myButton" value="Click To Open Instructions">Click To Open Instructions</button>

 <div style="display:none;" id="myDIV">
</div>
```