# How to display div after click the button in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have following DIV . I want to display the DIV after button click .Now it is display none

```
<div  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > WELCOME</div>
<input type="button" name="answer" >
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357291/javascript-show-element-on-click

Comment: Unfortunately, every single answer here suggests `onclick` attributes. Please see [Show/hide 'div' using JavaScript](/q/21070101/4642212) instead. Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

HTML Code:

```
<div id="welcomeDiv"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > WELCOME</div>
<input type="button" name="answer" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv()" />
```

Javascript:

```
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
}
```

See the Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/vzmnJ/

Comment: Ahsan Rathod , Thanks . How to display array Div usibng javascript .can u help me ?     <div style="float:left; width:420px; padding:10px 0px;display:none;"   class="answer_list"   id="welcomeDiv" >
  <?php         
  $query1= "select * from  tblanswers where questionID ='$question'  and  productID='$product_id' ";      
  $result1=mysql_query($query1);      
  while($qwe=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
  {
  ?>
  <input type="radio" name="answer[<?php echo $question; ?>]" value="<?php  echo $qwe['answer_id']; ?>" /><?php  echo $qwe['text']; ?> 
  <br />  
  <?php } ?>
  </div>

Comment: It only shows the button but doesn't show the text when I click in

Answer (score 16):

**HTML**

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display:none;" class="answer_list" >WELCOME</div>
<input type="button" name="answer" onclick="ShowDiv()" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
function ShowDiv() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "";
}
```

Or if you wanted to use jQuery with a nice little animation:

```
<input id="myButton" type="button" name="answer" />

$('#myButton').click(function() {
  $('#myDiv').toggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Comment: Your JQuery code is much more elegant that doing the same with document.getElementById - of course useful only when using JQuery :D

Comment: @MarcinCylke, great observation :P

Comment: if I do it with JS the block disappears after i reload the page but i want the box to stay until i explicitly close it. How I can do it?

Comment: It only shows the button but doesn't show the text when I click in

Answer (score 4):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showDiv(toggle){
document.getElementById(toggle).style.display = 'block';
}
</script>

<input type="button" name="answer" onclick="showDiv('toggle')">Show</input>

<div id="toggle" style="display:none">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > WELCOME</div>
<input type="button" name="answer" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('answer_list')[0].style.display = 'auto';">
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName will return a whole set of items.. you need to declare which one you want to change like this getElementsByClassName('foo')[0].style.display...

Comment: @James Hill: Do you want to declare a function for this case?
var fooJames = function(id){var d = document.getElementById(id);if(d.style.display=='block')d.style.display='none';return;
d.style.display='block';
}

In germany we call this: Mit Kanonen auf Spatzen schießen!

Comment: @Walialu, I understand what you're saying, but as a general rule, inline JS is poor practice. The OP probably has other JS running on the site. I placed my logic in a function so that it could be added to one of the .js files that he/she is already referencing. FYI - this is a good read: http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/.

Comment: how to get the displayed content collapse on another click ?