# Web form that displays user input on same page without page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to design a web app that includes a web form for data submission. This form should allow the user to add multiple data components before a final "SUBMIT" pushes it all to a database. In order to do this well, I want the user to see the cumulative progress as he/she inputs data.

For example, a possible (very basic) user flow is in the image below.

[image]

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this. I was thinking some sort of Javascript (or perhaps JQuery) that appends to a variable that is displayed in a div (kind of like in the dozens of questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957443/how-to-display-div-after-click-the-button-in-javascript)), but I can't figure out how to give that variable the proper scope.

How would one go about making this functionality without a page reload? I know I could do it simply with a GET or POST, but that requires a refresh on every click which dramatically slows down the process.

Comment: take a look at http://knockoutjs.com/index.html

Comment: You can made the final submit with serialize of data in jquery ajax.

Comment: a simple way would be to just use jquery and add the text of the input on click of the button. https://jsfiddle.net/ts1v5vse/

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: Look up "AJAX" if you want to submit data to the server without a page reload.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly append the text to a variable each time, and then update the display - if you need more control.

However, a primitive solution would be to just append the text to the DOM.

```
document.getElementById('addBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Get the input's content
  var input = document.getElementById('textInput');
  var text = input.value;

  //Create a div with the new content  
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(text); 
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent);

  // Add the input's content to the display
  var display = document.getElementById('display');
  display.appendChild(newDiv);

  // Clear the input
  input.value = '';
});
```

And the HTML to match:

```
<input id="textInput" type="text" />
<button id="addBtn">Add text</button>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var button = document.getElementById("addText"),
    input = document.getElementById("input"),
    output = document.getElementById("output");

button.onclick = function() {
  output.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div>' + input.value + "</div>");
  input.value = '';
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
<button id="addText">Add Text</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```