# How to make div appear on button click using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a div appear on button click which I've not succeeded from the below code.Please let me know if I've done any thing wrong in the code.

```js
function showDiv() {
  document.getElementById('sign-in').style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-default log-bar" href="#" role="button" onclick="showDiv()">Login</a>


<div id="sign-in" class="login" style="display: none;">
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group inline-form">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" Placeholder="email">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group inline-form">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default ">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: have you used script tag for JavaScript Function? Just Confirming

Comment: spelling mistake. It should be document.getElementById("sign-in");

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957443/how-to-display-div-after-click-the-button-in-javascript

Comment: I hope you have simplified the code, but the function should be between script tags, futhermore, is getElementById, instead getElementByid.  You should also instead using <a role="button"> use an <input type="button">

Comment: thankyou didn't noticed the 'i', but still not working.

Comment: @ZahidMustafa yea actually the JS code is in another file , I've given the src link in the html.

Comment: @srikarreddy bro change spelling it will work out

Comment: Thankyou @Diego I've changed the tag <a role="button"> to <input type="button"> and now its working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

change `getElementByid` to `getElementById` (`i` to `I`)

```js
function showDiv() {
  document.getElementById('sign-in').style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-default log-bar" href="#" role="button" onclick="showDiv()">Login</a>


<div id="sign-in" class="login" style="display: none;">
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group inline-form">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" Placeholder="email">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group inline-form">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default ">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typed wrong  `document.getElementByid` it should be capital `I` `document.getElementById`

```js
function showDiv() {
  document.getElementById('sign-in').style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-default log-bar" href="#" role="button" onclick="showDiv()">Login</a>


<div id="sign-in" class="login" style="display: none;">
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group inline-form">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" Placeholder="email">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group inline-form">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default ">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple

```
<script>
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('sign-in').style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById()` is a function and its case sensitive . You need to write `getElementByid()` as `getElementById()`.

**Note:-** *i* in `getElementById()` should be capital .

Answer (score -1):

Can I strongly, strongly suggest that you use jQuery to do this - it makes this task trivial on all browsers.  To do this with jQuery, perform the following steps.

Include the jQuery script library in your web page `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`.

Add an id property to your button `<a class="btn btn-default log-bar" href="#" id="loginButton" role="button" onclick = "showDiv()" >Login</a>`.

Add the following Javascript to your page:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#loginButton").click(function() {
            $("#sign-in").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```