# show hidden div content when button is pressed

Tags: php, jquery

Hi guys? how can i hide div content until a button is pressed?. Can anyone help me please.I want this div not to show up until the "add new teacher" button in the table is pressed. This is the div content which i want it to be hidden until the button is pressed

```
     <div id="myform">
<p align="center">
<strong>
Add information for new teacher here
</strong></p>
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
  <table align="center" id="forms">
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">First name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="first_name" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Last name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="last_name" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Subjects:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="subjects" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Phonenumber:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="phonenumber" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Email:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="email" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Username:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="username" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">Password:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="password" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Insert record" id="hideit"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

And this is my table which contain "Add New Teacher" button

```
    <p align="center">
<strong>
List of teachers in Minaki Sec school
</strong></p>
<table border="1" align="center" class="altrowstable" id="alternatecolor">
  <tr id="row">
    <th>teacher id</th>
    <th>first name</th>
    <th>last name</th>
    <th>subjects</th>
    <th>Phonenumber</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>username</th>
    <th>password</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
    <th>Details</th>
  </tr>
  <?php do { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row_teacherrec['teacher_id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_teacherrec['first_name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_teacherrec['last_name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_teacherrec['subjects']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_teacherrec['phonenumber']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_teacherrec['email']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_teacherrec['username']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row_teacherrec['password']; ?></td>
      <td><button onclick="location.href= 'edit_teacher.php? teacher_id=<?php echo $row_teacherrec['teacher_id']; ?>'">Edit</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="location.href= 'delete_teacher.php? teacher_id=<?php echo $row_teacherrec['teacher_id']; ?>'">Delete</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="location.href= 'edit_teacher.php? teacher_id=<?php echo $row_teacherrec['teacher_id']; ?>'">Details</button></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_teacherrec = mysql_fetch_assoc($teacherrec)); ?>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="8"></td>
    <td colspan="6" align="center"><button id="showit" onclick="location.href='teacher.php'">+Add new Teacher</button></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: did you try anything ?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357291/javascript-show-element-on-click

Answer (score 3):

Try it like,

```
$(function(){
   $('button#showit').on('click',function(){  
      $('#myform').show();
   });
});
```

**Initially** the `div` should be `hidden` like

```
<div id="myform" style="display:none">
.....
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the following changes in you code:

```
<div id="myform" style="display:none;">
```

Add the style in your div which you want to hide.

And Modify your button code as:

```
<button id="showit">+Add new Teacher</button>
```

And add this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#showit").click(function(){
       $("#myform").css("display","block");
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you.. I did exactly as you said and its working just like i needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:none` style to your div, then call `$("#div-id").show();` on button click.

```
<div id="myform" style="display:none">
  // contents here
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

on your new teacher form add an inline style to hide the form

```
<div id="myform" style="display:none">
```

or within your jQuery simply add

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // hide form on page load
    $('#myform').hide();

    // when button is pressed
    $('button').on('click',function(){  
      $('#myform').show();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery **hide** and **show** functions.

HERE

[Show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

[Hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('.button_name').click(function(){  
      $('#myform').show();
    });
 });





<button class="button_name">


    <div id="myform" style="display:none">
```

or using java script

```
function new_disp(){
   document.getElementById('myform').style.display='block';
 }




<button onclick='new_disp();'>


    <div id="myform" style="display:none">
```