# show and hide div onclick

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I create this code to show and hide div this code work but when i use it with php not work correctly when i click show for the first div he show me the div
but when i click the second he show me the first not the second how to solve this?

```
    include("connect.php");
    $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_codelibrary order by db_id desc")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
  echo'<div id="no-more-tables">
            <table class="col-md-12 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">
                <thead class="cf">';
echo"<tr>";
echo"<th style='background:#f7ac01;font-size:13px;vertical-align: middle;text-align:center' rowspan='2'>Title</th>
<th style='background:#f7ac01;font-size:13px;vertical-align: middle;text-align:center' rowspan='2'>Code</th>";
 echo"</tr></thead><tbody>";          
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $title=$row['db_title'];
        $code=$row['db_code'];
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td data-title='Title'>";echo $title;echo'<div id="opener"><a href="#1" name="1">Show Code</a></div>';echo"<br/>";echo'<div id="upbutton"><a onclick="return hide();">Hide Code</a></div>'; echo"</td>";         
echo"<td data-title='Code'>";echo"<pre><code class='' >&lt;";?><?php echo $row['db_code'];?><?php echo"&gt;</code></pre>";echo"</td>";          
    }
    ?>
            </body>

        <script> 
            function show() { 
                if(document.getElementById('benefits').style.display=='none') { 
                    document.getElementById('benefits').style.display='block'; 
                } 
                return false;
            } 
            function hide() { 
                if(document.getElementById('benefits').style.display=='block') { 
                    document.getElementById('benefits').style.display='none'; 
                } 
                return false;
            }   
        </script>
```

Comment: you can use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to show and hide

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript show element on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357291/javascript-show-element-on-click)

Comment: @guradio That is a jQuery function..

Comment: @Xorifelse it is tagged jQuery

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya not duplicate my code work for one div but when i have a loop in php he work for the first the other show also the first div not the div relate for the click

Comment: If your `id='benefits'` is inside of a loop, then you will have multiple `id`s on page. An `id` is only meant to appear once, as such your JavaScript will select the first the `id` it comes across. Please update your question to show the opening `}` is.

Comment: @Gary please check above i edit the code like you say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an html in a loop where you are using fixed id value instead of a dynamic one. This cause an id conflict. So your code will not work as desired. This only takes the first id of the page always.

I have written some dynamic content as per your requirement below:

```
    <style>
    .buttonCode{
        border:1px solid #000;
        background-color:#ccc;
        border-radius:5px;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
    for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
        $title = "Title-".$i;
        $content = "Content-".$i;
        echo $title;
        echo'<br>';
        echo'<a class="showContent buttonCode">Show Code</a>';
        echo'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        echo'<a class="hideContent buttonCode">Hide Code</a>'; 
        echo'<br>';
        echo"<pre><code class='benefits' style='display:none;'>&lt;".$content."&gt;</code></pre>";
        echo'<br>';
    }
    ?>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('.showContent').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).nextAll(':has(.benefits):first').find('.benefits').show();
    });
    $('.hideContent').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).nextAll(':has(.benefits):first').find('.benefits').hide();
    });
    </script>
```

Hope this will help you.

If you want it with javascript only then you can do like below:

```
    <style>
    .buttonCode{
        border:1px solid #000;
        background-color:#ccc;
        border-radius:5px;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
    for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
        $title = "Title-".$i;
        $content = "Content-".$i;
        echo $title;
        echo'<br>';
        echo'<a class="buttonCode" onclick="showbenefit('.$i.')">Show Code</a>';
        echo'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        echo'<a class="buttonCode" onclick="hidebenefit('.$i.')">Hide Code</a>'; 
        echo'<br>';
        echo"<pre><code class='benefits' id='benefits-".$i."' style='display:none;'>&lt;".$content."&gt;</code></pre>";
        echo'<br>';
    }
    ?>
    <script> 
    function showbenefit(s) { 
        if(document.getElementById('benefits-'+s).style.display=='none') { 
            document.getElementById('benefits-'+s).style.display='block'; 
        } 
        return false;
    } 
    function hidebenefit(h) { 
        if(document.getElementById('benefits-'+h).style.display=='block') { 
            document.getElementById('benefits-'+h).style.display='none'; 
        } 
        return false;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Where does this question ask anything about [tag:jquery]?

Answer (score 0):

```js
        function show_hide(){ 
            if(document.getElementById('benefits').style.display=='none') { 
                document.getElementById('benefits').style.display='block'; 
            } 
   else if(document.getElementById('benefits').style.display=='block') { 
                document.getElementById('benefits').style.display='none'; 
            }
          
        }
```

```html
<div id="benefits" style="display:block">test</div>
  <a href="javascript:void" onclick="show_hide() ">Submit</a>
```

Hello! Hope this help you!

p.s you can use .toggle() to show and hide in JQuery