# How to display div on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this HTML code. I have a slideshow with some images. And I've a linked div for each image that contains a description of that image. Every "div" with class "product" has one CSS property, display: none.

When I click on one image I want to display only the info of that image. Each image is linked to its description by a data-attribute called "data-code". How can do it?

```
enter code here

<div class="slideshow">
    <img data-code="1" >
    <img data-code="2" >
    <img data-code="3" >
    <img data-code="4" >
```

```
<div class="productWrapper">
    <div class="product" data-code="1">Some info</div>
    <div class="product" data-code="2">Some info</div>
    <div class="product" data-code="3">Some info</div>
    <div class="product" data-code="4">Some info</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post the jQuery you tried please

Comment: Are you using plain old JavaScript, or jQuery?

Comment: For plain JavaScript, you should be able to build off this older answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357291/javascript-show-element-on-click

Answer (score -1):

In Jquery do this; 
Then create a button in html that has an id as showElement

```
$("#showElement").click(function(){  
    $(".slideshow").slideDown();   
  });
```